# Add a processing instruction to an existing XML document using libxml++

Tags: c++, xml, libxml2

I'm trying to add a processing instruction node to an existing XML document to have a XSL transformation applied to the document when displayed in a browser. I looked up how to do it using `libxml++` classes but couldn't find it out, so I tried using `libxml2`. This is what I came up with:

```c
xmlpp::Document* Doc = Parser->get_document();

// Set processing instruction for stylesheet
const xmlNodePtr PINode = xmlNewDocPI(
    Doc->cobj(),
    reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>("xml-stylesheet"),
    reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>("href=\"../stylesheet.xslt\" type=\"text/xsl\"")
);

if (PINode == NULL) {
     // Never get here
}

Doc->write_to_file_formatted("mydoc.xml", "utf-8");
```

The processing instruction node is not written into the document. So what am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that just calling `xmlNewDocPI` is not enough. It creates the processing instruction node and somehow associates it to the document but **it doesn't actually attach it to the document**.

For that purpose some of the `xmlAdd*` functions must be called and, since I need the PI to be included right below the XML declaration and not nested within the documents root node, I had to use the following:

```c
xmlAddPrevSibling(Doc->get_root_node()->cobj(), PINode);
```

It looks kind of hackish but works. So the full snippet for the working code gets like this:

```c
xmlpp::Document* Doc = Parser->get_document();

// Set processing instruction for stylesheet
const xmlNodePtr PINode = xmlNewDocPI(
    Doc->cobj(),
    reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>("xml-stylesheet"),
    reinterpret_cast<xmlChar*>("href=\"../stylesheet.xslt\" type=\"text/xsl\"")
);

if (PINode != NULL) {
    xmlAddPrevSibling(Doc->get_root_node()->cobj(), PINode);
}

Doc->write_to_file_formatted("mydoc.xml", "utf-8");
```

Comment: This isn't 'hackish', it's the right way to do it; you need to tell a document WHERE to put any node; a processing instruction can potentially go anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that it is the proper way to do it. I just found it *weird*, rather than *hackish*, that the PI node's location had to be referred to as 'root node's previous sibling'.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean; I was referring to the fact that you had to add it at all. It's a common misconception that the root element is the root of the document; the document itself is actually an XML node, and the root element is a child of it. If there's a way of inserting the processing instruction as the first child of the document itself, that should also do it. 'Root node' isn't strictly accurate, I believe you're referring to the root *element*. I'm surprised that the libxml library uses 'get_root_node', that's kind of misleading. I know .NET uses 'DocumentElement' for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Adding a processing instruction to an XML document can be done in pure XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:processing-instruction name="xml-stylesheet">
    <xsl:text>href="../stylesheet.xslt" type="text/xsl"</xsl:text>
  </xsl:processing-instruction>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
  <xsl:apply-templates/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this transformation is applied to any XML document, such as the one below:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

**the wanted result is produced**:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="../stylesheet.xslt" type="text/xsl"?>
<nums>
   <num>01</num>
   <num>02</num>
   <num>03</num>
   <num>04</num>
   <num>05</num>
   <num>06</num>
   <num>07</num>
   <num>08</num>
   <num>09</num>
   <num>10</num>
</nums>
```

Comment: @AntonioPérez: I am glad that you find my answer useful. Please, reflect this via upvote/acceptance. Also, please note that this isnt a "workaround" but the *main* solution. XSLT is a language specially designed for XML transformations and is superior to using any other technology that wasn't designed with XML transformations in mind.

Comment: The point is that my application is written in C++ and it is meant to edit/create the XML files. I'm using `libxm++` for that purpose, so implementing your proposed solution would mean that I'd have to keep the XSLT code in a file or hardcoded and use `libxslt` library (or another library) to apply the transformation to the file. For me, this is a workaround as compared to including the processing instruction into the file at the same time as editing its contents and not having to include another dependency (XSLT processing library).

Comment: @AntonioPérez: You can have the XSLT transformation in your C++ file. There is a way of loading an XML/XSLT file from string. Or this can be in a separate file that is included. Or, this can be a string in a resource file, ..., etc. As for not wanting to use an XSLT processor -- well, we can only use Assembler, can't we ? :)

Comment: Dimitre: right, your proposed solution works. But I eventually found a solution that is better in terms of performance and code maintenance.

Comment: @AntonioPérez: Such conclusions, of course are too-absolute and biased. There were the times when programmers believed that using Assembler is better in terms of performance/maintenance than using Fortran :)

Comment: Dimitre: my conclusions are not for the general case, just for **this** one :)